# Apache2 restart failed on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

when i am trying to restart apache server from ubuntu, its showing as fail... 
i typed the command as,
$service apache2 restart

it shows,

- Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]

when i checked in log file, in var/apache2/errorlog the description provided is,

> [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1263] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) 
>   PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most likely because you are not using sudo when running the command, try:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

1. On linux/ubuntu we can restart the appache server :-

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
2. In a different way

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Debian/Ubuntu Linux Specific Commands
You can either use service or /etc/init.d/ command as follows on Debian Linux version 7.x or Ubuntu Linux version Ubuntu 14.10 or older:

**Restart Apache 2 web server, enter:**

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

OR

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

**To stop Apache 2 web server, enter:**

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

OR

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

OR

```
$ sudo service apache2 stop
```

**To start Apache 2 web server, enter:**

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

OR

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

OR

```
$ sudo service apache2 start
```

A note about Debian/Ubuntu Linux systemd users
Use the following commands on Debian Linux version 8.x+ or Ubuntu Linux version Ubuntu 15.04+ or above:

### Start command

```
systemctl start apache2.service
```

### Stop command

```
systemctl stop apache2.service
```

### Restart command

```
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

CentOS/RHEL (Red Hat) Linux version 4.x/5.x/6.x or older specific commands

### Start

```
service httpd start
```

### Stop

```
service httpd stop
```

### Restart

```
service httpd restart
```

CentOS/RHEL (Red Hat) Linux version 7.x or newer specific commands
Most modern distro now using systemd, so you need to use the following command:

### Start command

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

### Stop command

```
systemctl stop httpd.service
```

### Restart command

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Generic method to start/stop/restart Apache on a Linux/Unix
The syntax is as follows (must be run as root user):

### stop it

```
apachectl -k stop
```

### restart it

```
apachectl -k restart
```

### graceful restart it

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

### Start it

```
apachectl -f /path/to/your/httpd.conf
apachectl -f /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

### If some other service occupied on port 80 (Eg.: Skype),

try the code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

followed by Code:

```
sudo killall apache2
```

then make sure no services are running on port 80 Code:

```
sudo netstat -l|grep www
```

then (re)start apache Code:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stop the apache server and start again.
In ubuntu terminal type command

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

and then start apache server again